# How do I split a column containing a path into individual columns based on '/' in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ex, Column contains this

```
/RS2015/DCA/Training/Summary
```

while returning rows using select I want to split them in different column values based on "/".

Comment: Are the number of columns fixed ?

Comment: No, the columns should be returned based on the path. if path is "/RS2015/DCA/Training" the return col1=RS2015, col2=DCa and col3=Training. if path is longer then return columns based on path size.

Comment: Is there any maximum limit ?

Comment: No limit on columns

Comment: This is a bad design -- any process that returns a variable number of columns will not work well with other aspects of SQL -- what you want is a variable number of rows.

Comment: "*the columns should be returned based on the path*" - this is impossible. The result of a SQL query must have the same number of columns for **every** row. You can't have 4 columns in the first row, 6 columns in the second and 2 columns in the third row.

Answer (score 0):

I have a TVF which may help.  Currently returns 9 positions, but it is easy enough to expand.

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '/RS2015/DCA/Training/Summary'
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row](Stuff(@String,1,1,''),'/')
```

Returns

```
Pos1    Pos2    Pos3        Pos4     Pos5   Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
RS2015  DCA     Training    Summary  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Note: I used STUFF() to strip the first /.  This would be optional

This can also be used in a Cross Apply

```
Select A.ID
       B.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row](Stuff(A.PathString,1,1,''),'/') B
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
     From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
)
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('John Cappelletti',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `dynamic sql` and `xml`

```
DECLARE @str   VARCHAR(8000) = '/RS2015/DCA/Training/Summary',
        @start INT= 1,
        @count INT,
        @sql VARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @count = Len(@str) - Len(Replace(@str, '/', ''))

SET @sql = ';WITH Split_Names AS
            (
            SELECT CONVERT(XML,''<Names><name>'' + REPLACE(''' + Stuff(@str, 1, 1, '') + ''',''/'', ''</name><name>'') + ''</name></Names>'') AS xmlname
            )
            SELECT 
            '
WHILE @start <= @count
  BEGIN
      SET @sql +=Concat('xmlname.value(''/Names[1]/name[', @start, ']'',''varchar(500)'') as [column',@start,'], ')
      SET @start+=1
  END

SET @sql =LEFT(@sql, Len(@sql) - 1)
SET @sql+= ' FROM Split_Names'

--select @sql
EXEC( @sql)
```

**Result :**

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ column1 ║ column2 ║ column3  ║ column4 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ RS2015  ║ DCA     ║ Training ║ Summary ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```